# Fancybox and Awkward slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am trying to get the fancybox plugin to work nicely with the awkward slider.

The fancybox pop-up works but only for the first image. The other images don't work.

It seems that once the awkward plugin has been clicked the fancybox plugin is not working anymore.

No firebug errors in console. Here is the example: http://www.awkward.interfacecreation.com/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awkward slider creates the elements on demand and events are lost for unloaded elements.

Try using the .live function of jQuery to call the events

```
$(".awkward a").live("click",function(){
  $.fancybox({
    'href'          : 'bigimage.jpg'
  });
});
```